# Executing recursive query in DB2 I received a SQL code -340

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I wrote the follow recursive query that gives me the list of IDs that I need and it is working just fine:

```
 with rec_table (emailid) as
 ((select email.id  as emailid from email, addressee, address, use, user 
   where email.id = addressee.EMAIL and addressee.to = address.ID 
   and address.id = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))
 union
 (select email.id as emailid from email, address, use, user 
  where email.from = address.id 
  and address.ID = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))

union all

select email.id as emailid from email, rec_table as x
 where email.contained_in = x.emailid)

select * from rec_table
```

However, if I need to do something more elaborated with the result of the query, like in the query below, I received an error

```
 with rec_table (emailid) as
 ((select email.id  as emailid from email, addressee, address, use, user 
   where email.id = addressee.EMAIL and addressee.to = address.ID 
   and address.id = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))
 union
 (select email.id as emailid from email, address, use, user 
  where email.from = address.id 
  and address.ID = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))

union all

select email.id as emailid from email, rec_table as x 
where email.contained_in = x.emailid)

select user.id, address.id from rec_table as x, addressee, address, use, user  
where  x.emailid = addressee.EMAIL and addressee.to = address.ID 
and address.id = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id
```

I received sql error code -340:

> SQL Error [42726]: The common table expression "" has the same
>   identifier as another occurrence of a common table expression
>   definition within the same statement.. SQLCODE=-340, SQLSTATE=42726,
>   DRIVER=4.16.53 SQL Error [56098]: An error occurred during implicit
>   system action type "2".  Information returned for the error includes
>   SQLCODE "-340", SQLSTATE "42726" and message tokens "".. SQLCODE=-727,
>   SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.16.53   The common table expression "" has
>   the same identifier as another occurrence of a common table expression
>   definition within the same statement.. SQLCODE=-340, SQLSTATE=42726,
>   DRIVER=4.16.53

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the recursion initialization part into its own CTE:

```
with blah (emailid) as 
 ((select email.id  as emailid from email, addressee, address, use, user 
   where email.id = addressee.EMAIL and addressee.to = address.ID 
   and address.id = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))
 union
 (select email.id as emailid from email, address, use, user 
  where email.from = address.id 
  and address.ID = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id and user.id = user_t(121))
),
rec_table (emailid) as (

  select emailid from blah
 union all
  select email.id as emailid from email, rec_table as x 
  where email.contained_in = x.emailid)

select user.id, address.id from rec_table as x, addressee, address, use, user  
where  x.emailid = addressee.EMAIL and addressee.to = address.ID 
and address.id = use.ADDRESS and use.user = user.id
```

NB: not tested.